# WCF - How to correctly configure MVC Client consuming WCF Service?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, webhttpbinding, wcf-configuration

I am perfectly aware that this problem has already been discussed a whole lot of times, but it is a specific configuration of my project that I miss to grasp which makes my Service - Client communication go wrong. I ask for your help in this matter. Excuse my stupid errors, I am very new to WCF and REST services in general.

So, basically, I want to create a MVC application that would consume a WCF REST service hosted on the IIS Server.

I have created a WCF Service Application with the following **Service Contract**:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IUserService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "/ListaUtilizatori/")]
    DataSet ListaUtilizatori();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "/DetaliiUtilizator/{id}")]
    DataSet DetaliiUtilizator(String id);


    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "/AdaugaUtilizator")]
    String AdaugaUtilizator(Utilizator utilizator);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT",
      RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
      ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
      UriTemplate = "/ActualizeazaUtilizator")]
    String ActualizeazaUtilizator(Utilizator utilizator);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE",
       RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       UriTemplate = "/StergeUtilizator/{id}")]
    String StergeUtilizator(String id);
}
```

I implemented the methods correctly and in the `web.config` file I configured the Service Model as such:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RESTService.UserService" behaviorConfiguration="RESTServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding_IUserService" contract="RESTService.IUserService" behaviorConfiguration="RESTEndpointBehavior"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>        
        <behavior name="RESTServiceBehaviour">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RESTEndpointBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="True"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebHttpBinding_IUserService" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Afterwards, I published the WCF App on the IIS Server and it worked just fine returning the expected JSON format response in the browser.

I created a MVC app to whom I added a service reference to the published WCF service and named it `UserServiceReference`. Strangely, no `system.serviceModel` node was added or configured in the MVC's `web.config`, so I added manually the following:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RESTEndpoint">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebHttpBinding_IUserService" />        
      </webHttpBinding>      
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/RESTUserService/UserService.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding_IUserService" 
                behaviorConfiguration="RESTEndpoint" contract="UserServiceReference.IUserService" name="WebHttpBinding_IUserService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Then I tried to test the functionality by creating a client in one of the app's controllers with the following code:

```
UserServiceReference.UserServiceClient client = new UserServiceReference.UserServiceClient();
            DataSet ds = client.DetaliiUtilizator("2");
UserServiceReference.UserDataContractUtilizator utilizator = new UserServiceReference.UserDataContractUtilizator();
```

When I run my app I get this error in the browser:

```
[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.]  System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +1390    System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout) +55

[EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost/RESTUserService/UserService.svc/DetaliiUtilizator that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.]
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +153



System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +336
   MVCApp.UserServiceReference.IUserService.DetaliiUtilizator(String id) +0
   MVCApp.UserServiceReference.UserServiceClient.DetaliiUtilizator(String id) in D:\F5IT\PROJECT\RESTService\MVCApp\Service References\UserServiceReference\Reference.cs:308
   MVCApp.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in D:\F5IT\PROJECT\RESTService\MVCApp\Controllers\HomeController.cs:34
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +61
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9744373
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
Source Error: 

Line 306:        
Line 307:        public System.Data.DataSet DetaliiUtilizator(string id) {
Line 308:            return base.Channel.DetaliiUtilizator(id);
Line 309:        }
Line 310:
```

I added these things as a compilation of all the posts I have read. It must be a certain error in all this code. What could it be?

Thank you so much!

Comment: from the error: `See InnerException, if present, for more details.`

Comment: @JamieR I added the whole exception.

Comment: Are you sure that `http://localhost/RESTUserService/UserService.svc/DetaliiUtilizator` is the correct endpoint?

Comment: No, the endpoint is `http://localhost/RESTUserService/UserService.svc/DetaliiUtilizator /{id}`, that is why the method in the code has a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I have eventually realized which the problem was in this article:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2012/03/25/mixing-add-service-reference-and-wcf-web-http-a-k-a-rest-endpoint-does-not-work/

It seems like adding a service reference to a WCF service with an endpoint using `WebHttpBinding` will result in useless auto-generated Client code.